# Is there a way to trigger http triggered Google Cloud Functions from China IP's?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions to collect log style data sent from an app. This is working well with the exception of China where I believe the firewall is blocking triggers from China based IP's. Is anyone aware of a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform has a server in Hong Kong, which should make access easier to GCP. There are some sites that you can confirm if your application URL is available on China - for example this one [here](https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/china-firewall-test). This way, you will be able to check if something is being blocked on China's side.

Besides that, indeed, you can create functions to get the IP address from the client side as you requested. On this link [here](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6fffffb45ee5cbfbca6c3511e5d19528), there is a possible solution to get the IP addresses and on this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), there is more information regarding callable functions on Firebase, to retrieve data.

Let me know if the information helped you!